# how to find the string between '>#tableDiags' and '#tableDiage<' using regex

Tags: angular, regex

Help me how to get string between these two string '>#tableDiags' and '#tableDiage<' with special character.
Also there can be multiple strings like this and wanted to get all the strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
/\>#tableDiags(.*?)\#tableDiage</gm
```

**Explanation**

- `\>` matches the character > literally (case sensitive)
- `#tableDiags` matches the characters `#tableDiags` literally (case sensitive)
- **`(.*?)`** where `.` matches any character and `*?` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
- `\#` matches the character `#` literally (case sensitive)
- `tableDiage<` matches the characters `tableDiage<` literally (case sensitive)

**Global pattern flags**

- `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
- `m` modifier: multi line. Causes `^` and `$` to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below pattern and working as expected
(?<=>#tableVits)\w+(.*?#tableVite<)